# List filtering on a list display/Edit form

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-on-prem, list-form, 2019

First of all, I don't use SharePoint online. SharePoint 2016 updated to 2019 here.

I have a list of items with a ton of columns. When I click on an item it takes me to that list items display form. What I want to do is add another web part to the bottom of this form that displays a list but that second list is filtered by the ID of the first list's item that was selected. How do I go about filtering that second list based off what was selected.

Major constraint is that we don't use the publishing features nor can I have them activated so content query is not viable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using SP 2019, right? Are you using modern experience or classic experience list forms?

Comment: SP 2019. Although the server is set up to display modern pages, I've overridden the setting for the list to display in classic.

Comment: If you are using classic experience, you can use connected list web parts on list form for your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter items of one list according to selected item of another list.

Edit page -> Edit web prat -> Connections -> Get Filter Values From -> Set connection settings -> When you select items in the 1 list, items with same title will display in the A list.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was playing with this option but considering that I've no experience with it, I found it very user-UNfriendly. I'll give this a shot on Monday and let you know how it went. Thanks for the assist. Just so I understand the screenshot above, The provider Field is from the source list and the Consumer field is from the list I want to filter?

Comment: Yes, the Provider Field is from the source list and the Consumer Field is from the list I want to filter.